# Proof of convergence of sequences and Fourier series convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

So the question is from a textbook. I have spent some time thinking about this, but I do not think I have an adequate answer. It is the following:

> Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be two sequences such that the series
>   $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} a_n$ converges and $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1$. Both $a_n$ and $b_n$ are nonnegative.
>
> a) Prove that the series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} b_n$ converges.
>
> b) Prove that the Fourier series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (a_n \cos n x +
> b_n \sin n x)$ converges uniformly and absolutely on $\mathbb{R}$.

The problem is that I am stumped on the first part. While it seems intuitively obvious that as $n$ approaches infinity, $b_n$ would have to converge in order for the fraction $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ to converge, but how would one go about proving this rigorously?

As for the second part, is the answer a corollary to answering the first one? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is $a_n$ absolutely convergent?

Comment: It is only given that it converges, absolute convergence cannot be assumed.

Comment: Okay does it say that the sequences are nonnegative? Because as it is written there is not true see my answer below.

Comment: If $a_n \ge 0$ then the sequence **is** absolutely convergent!!!

Comment: Note, with $a_n = (-1)^n {1 \over n}$ and $b_n = a_n + {1 \over n \log n}$ we have $\sum_n a_n$ conditionally convergent, ${a _n \over b_b} \to 1$ and $\sum_n b_n $ divergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** First the OP did not mention that the sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ are nonnegative.

The statement is true. Since $a_n$ is nonnegative we have $|a_n|=a_n$ and therefore $\sum |a_n|$ is convergent.

Furthermore we have also $\frac{a_n}{b_n}\to 1$. So there exist an $N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have:
\begin{align}
|\frac{a_n}{b_n}-1| < \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
So: 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}<\frac{a_n}{b_n} < \frac{3}{2}\\
\end{align}
And that means:
\begin{align}
b_n < 2a_n
\end{align}
So $\sum b_n$ converges by the comparison test. Since it is nonnegative it also converges absolutely. For the Fourier series note that we have:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty |(a_n\cos(nx) + b_n\sin(nx)) |\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty (|a_n| + |b_n|)
\end{align}
Since the RHS is convergent and the inequality holds for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the Fourier series converges uniformly and absolutely by the Weierstrass-M test.

Comment: I forgot to put in the statement saying that they are both non-negative! How does that change your answer?

Comment: @Mathmaniac the answer is totally different. I deleted the last one and added this one. I hope it helps you.