# Convergence of two sequences and Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

So the question is from a textbook. I have spent some time thinking about this, but I do not think I have an adequate answer. It is the following:

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be two sequences such that the series $\sum^{\inf}_{n=1} a_n$ converges and $\lim_{n->\inf}\frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1$

a) Prove that the series $\sum^{\inf}_{n=1} b_n$ converges.

b) Prove that the Fourier series $\sum^{\inf}_{n=1} (a_n cosn x+ b_n sinnx)$ converges unformly and absolutely on $R$.

The problem is that I am stumped on the first part. While it seems intuitively obvious that as n approaches infinity, $b_n$ would have to converge in order for the fraction $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ to converge, but how would one go about proving this rigorously?

As for the second part, is the answer a corollary to answering the first one? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You've already asked this question not even 1 hour previously: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524294/proof-of-convergence-of-sequences-and-fourier-series-convergence. Please do not post the same question twice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the user has asked the same question very recently: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524294/proof-of-convergence-of-sequences-and-fourier-series-convergence.

Comment: I will take down the question. However, would you be kind enough to help with the original question, if possible?